# Custom plugin documentation - Import Helper options

Tags: python, add-on, development

I'm a developer looking to write a plugin, but am having such a hard time finding docs on the options for many inbuilt blender functions.

Specifically today I'm trying to customise the `ImportHelper` that comes with `bpy_extras.io_utils` but the only documentation I can find are existing code examples by other users, and this unhelpful stub:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.io_utils.html#bpy_extras.io_utils.ImportHelper

Where am I not looking?

Comment: It's easier to check the source code: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/commit/5721b34e53640ce68875603a6842c528e1887dcd/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/io_utils.py#L91

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. Not super detailed but I can work through it from there.